# Firebase Crashlytics don't send crashes to console without VPN Proxy

Tags: android, firebase, vpn, crashlytics

I was trying to add firebase crashlytics to my android app. Everything works correctly but I can see crashes in the firebase console when I use VPN proxy on the Android device or on the windows that run an emulator. I connect from Iran country and unfortunately, my country is one of the sanctioned countries. Now I don't know, my problem is for Boycotting or my problem is from another where!
Had Somebody from Iran this problem? And if Yes, How solve this problem?

Comment: https://appmetrica.yandex.com/docs/mobile-reports/concepts/crash-dump-errors.html

Comment: https://sentry.io/for/mobile/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=9712148604&content=437248420223&utm_term=+crash%20+reporting&gclid=CjwKCAiAkan9BRAqEiwAP9X6UWLbBUOqb9l4Bzg6ByErN_4raZSRPW91xNxjtiZEkA9Oiweshon7WxoCqqAQAvD_BwE

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2163  البته داخل ایشو های فایربیس رو هم بهتره نگاه کنی